# Generate consensus layer configuration for private post-merge Ethereum network

Tags: genesis, validators, configuration, lighthouse, ssz

I want to deploy a private post-merge Ethereum network (i.e. a network that merges right from the genesis). For the execution layer, I created a `genesis.json` file with the appropriate parameters and I especially included the [deposit contract](https://github.com/protolambda/merge-genesis-tools/blob/master/README.md#deposit-contract). This gives something like this (note that some values were chosen arbitrarily for example purposes):

```json
{
  "config": {
    "chainId": 2023,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip150Block": 0,
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0,
    "byzantiumBlock": 0,
    "constantinopleBlock": 0,
    "petersburgBlock": 0,
    "istanbulBlock": 0,
    "muirGlacierBlock": 0,
    "berlinBlock": 0,
    "londonBlock": 0,
    "mergeForkBlock": 0,
    "mergeNetsplitBlock": 0,
    "shanghaiTime": 0,
    "terminalTotalDifficulty": 0,
    "terminalTotalDifficultyPassed": true
  },
  "nonce": "0x2023",
  "timestamp": "0x0",
  "extraData": "0x0",
  "gasLimit": "0x0",
  "difficulty": "0x0",
  "mixHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "number": "0x0",
  "gasUsed": "0x0",
  "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "alloc": {
    "0x4242424242424242424242424242424242424242": {
      "balance": "0x0",
      "code": "0x60806040...060b0033",
      "storage": {
        "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000022": "0xf5a5fd42d16a20302798ef6ed309979b43003d2320d9f0e8ea9831a92759fb4b",
        "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000023": "0xdb56114e00fdd4c1f85c892bf35ac9a89289aaecb1ebd0a96cde606a748b5d71",
        ...
        "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040": "0x985e929f70af28d0bdd1a90a808f977f597c7c778c489e98d3bd8910d31ac0f7"
      }
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

Regarding the consensus layer configuration, I started by defining a personal version of the [mainnet.yaml](https://github.com/ethereum/consensus-specs/blob/dev/configs/mainnet.yaml). Then, based on this configuration file, I want now to generate the necessary `genesis.ssz` state file. More precisely, I also want to generate `N` validators and have them registered in the `genesis.ssz` file. By that, I mean having the following (when parsed into json, with, for instance, lighthouse, `lcli pretty-ssz state_merge genesis.ssz | jq`):

```json
{
  ...
  "validators": [
    {
      "pubkey": "0xaf8140025e35bf66780ffe7d735465e8d1dcfd2e4fcee5c82ef1add9c6e9e1dc8a5b162ad44b1b1bc88f1d9715f89ebe",
      "withdrawal_credentials": "0x00fad2a6bfb0e7f1f0f45460944fbd8dfa7f37da06a4d13b3983cc90bb46963b",
      "effective_balance": "32000000000",
      "slashed": false,
      "activation_eligibility_epoch": "0",
      "activation_epoch": "0",
      "exit_epoch": "18446744073709551615",
      "withdrawable_epoch": "18446744073709551615"
    },
    ...  
    {
      "pubkey": "0x93adea4aed7faa99ad5757fffae398e38130a779b0796bc3ccac76b41dcacfc5d6807659e9afd1189da5aa9e1831d3e8",
      "withdrawal_credentials": "0x001414bfc6dacca55f974ec910893c8617f9c99da897534c637b50e9fc695323",
      "effective_balance": "32000000000",
      "slashed": false,
      "activation_eligibility_epoch": "0",
      "activation_epoch": "0",
      "exit_epoch": "18446744073709551615",
      "withdrawable_epoch": "18446744073709551615"
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

Furthermore, I want to run the lighthouse beacon node and validator clients. So, following the instructions on the [lighthouse documentation](https://lighthouse-book.sigmaprime.io/mainnet-validator.html), I created the validator keys using [stacking-deposit-cli](https://github.com/ethereum/staking-deposit-cli):

```bash
./deposit new-mnemonic
```

This command gives me a `validator_keys` directory with all the keys following standard [EIP-2335](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2335).

> Small question: this command also gives me a `deposit_data-<timestamp>.json` file with content as shown partially below. What is this deposit data?

```json
[
  {
    "pubkey": "aee7bbe42b35ecca52ea56c84f9d77d2ab1cdddde508e52faf368b1fde90aa81867e76d5f1a2799446f66ba9eb058057",
    "withdrawal_credentials": "00898b8a89a9a9774a788a2e94a2518b5a96b290e1bbe8d91237d05481344c72",
    "amount": 32000000000,
    "signature": "b56e25e7fbdb6cc9b28bd5987db2dc86b4e87db1d14f50e099616969a9011b757f48ca2c9142f5141bf056f4d6979c2413a6fdc0832fa04ddd6a214a3b50e4f428aaafbff50a691b526554d4817c10fcff72398eff61afbba2c3a298759a7de3",
    "deposit_message_root": "4982a3020192291799816c6c4675fa9fcd819f09ae89ed6400b3b7c451cac117",
    "deposit_data_root": "c09670ac47016683236b402d38cac7b01d3f26a6954852cb30a17ab0606bfdd8",
    "fork_version": "00000000",
    "network_name": "mainnet",
    "deposit_cli_version": "2.5.0"
  },
  ...
]
```

I can then later easily import these keys in the [lighthouse validator clients](https://lighthouse-book.sigmaprime.io/mainnet-validator.html#step-3-import-validator-keys-to-lighthouse) using:

```
lighthouse account validator import --directory /path/to/validator_keys
```

However, I'm missing something, which is having these newly created validators included in the `genesis.ssz` state file as claimed earlier. How can I achieve this? Also, am I missing something crucial in the consensus layer configuration?

Regarding the lighthouse beacon node client, how do I start them given the `genesis.ssz` generated? The documentation states that, for a [manual checkpoint sync](https://lighthouse-book.sigmaprime.io/checkpoint-sync.html#manual-checkpoint-sync), both `--checkpoint-state` and `--checkpoint-block` must be provided. Is the first one our `genesis.ssz` file? And what is the second one? How do I get it?

Thank you in advance for your help!